# How can I filter or subset multiple columns based on a greate than or less than criteria at the same time?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> head(ratio_da)
               Compound       PA1       PA2         PA3 PA1 : PA2 PA1 : PA3 PA2 : PA3
1 7.92_540.535223166667   3720068  42061995  22440957.7 0.0884425 0.1657714 1.8743405
2 7.64_538.520408833333 150348486 247654259 299620639.3 0.6070902 0.5017962 0.8265594
3 6.73_552.499681833333   2687581   5690404    869171.9 0.4723006 3.0921170 6.5469255
4      6.12_536.5044875  16289397  21130472  21314675.4 0.7708961 0.7642339 0.9913579
5 8.22_566.551271833333  24241911  49978630  48028396.5 0.4850455 0.5047412 1.0406059
6 8.64_594.582882166667   8772965  16609306  16694017.1 0.5281958 0.5255155 0.9949257
```

As you can see, the last three columns are the ratios of column PA1, PA2, and PA3. I would like to filter all ratio columns by this criteria: `>= 1.2 | <= 0.83`. I usually use this code:

```
test <- filter(ratio_da, ratio_da$`PA1 : PA2` >= 1.2, ratio_da$`PA1 : PA2` >= 0.83 | ratio_da$`PA1 : PA3` >= 1.2, ratio_da$`PA1 : PA3` >= 0.83 |ratio_da$`PA2 : PA3` >= 1.2, ratio_da$`PA2 : PA3` >= 0.83 )
```

Since I have tons of dataframes like this, I am trying to find a quicker way which can suit every input dataframe. So I tried `apply()`:

```
t <- tt[apply(tt[5:7],1,function(x) any(x >=1.2 | x <= 0.83)),]
```

...but this did not filter all raios at the same time. Any codes can fixs this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by `but this did not filter all raios at the same time` ? What is the output do you get when you use `apply` ? What do you want instead?

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

### base R

```r
rowSums(ratio_da[,5:7] >= 1.2 | ratio_da[,5:7] <= 0.83) > 0
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

or less-efficient:

```r
Reduce(`|`, lapply(ratio_da[,5:7], function(z) z >= 1.2 | z <= 0.83))
```

### dplyr

```r
rowSums(!between(ratio_da[,5:7], 0.83, 1.2)) > 0
```

(not much savings here)